# Removing MongoDB Array Element by Index Results in Null - Why?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Question:

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to remove an element from an array within a MongoDB document using the $unset operator. The element gets set to null, and I'm unsure why this behavior is occurring.

Context:

I have a MongoDB collection named "documents" with an array field named "arrayField". My goal is to remove an element from this array based on its index.

Issue:

When using the following code:

```
db.documents.updateOne(
  { _id: ObjectId("your-document-id") },
  { $unset: { ["arrayField." + indexToRemove]: 1 } }
);
```

The element at the specified index gets replaced with null instead of being completely removed from the array.

Comment: `$unset` is used to remove a field. For removing element in an array, use [$pull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#-pull)

Comment: From the `$unset` documentation: *When used with $ to match an array element, $unset replaces the matching element with null rather than removing the matching element from the array. This behavior keeps consistent the array size and element positions.*

Comment: @ray I do not want to pull the last element but one element in the array with an index

Comment: @Pointy Is see, I just do not need this behavior to keeps consistent the array size and element positions

Comment: @János $pull is not limited to the last element, but any element that match your criteria. Usually interacting with array elements with index is weird in MongoDB. More common way is to interacting with criteria.